# Frequency of a ring oscillator using transistors only

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

This is the standard design of a NOT gate without much sophistication:

[image]

I've used R1 = 1k \$ \Omega \$ and R2 = 100k \$ \Omega \$. The transistor model I use is BC107B.

In an attempt to create a seven-ring oscillator, I've connected seven of such NOT gates in series, and fed the output of the last gate to the first transistor's input.

I get an approximately rectangular waveform with a frequency around 50 MHz. I can't seem to account for the frequency in this case. There are no capacitors used, and there's not  any time delay component as such.

How are we generating this frequency in this case?

Can someone help me in figuring this out?

Comment: Transistors have their own capacitance, as does the wiring between them. Look at your transistor's datasheet and see what you can learn about the capacitances.

Comment: Yeah, I was going through the datasheet itself right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are no capacitors used, and there's not any time delay component as such

Those are assumptions, and not the good kind, I'm afraid. There are inherent delays due to the physics of the semiconductor, there are parasitic capacitances that cause the signals to have delays. On a breadboard you'll also have the parasitics of the PCB, the elements, themselves, etc -- all of these will contribute to a delay. That's what ring oscillators rely on. In general, no real-time circuit will have zero delay, otherwise [causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_(physics)) will be broken.

Comment: Very well. That's a good reason. Thanks. Also, do the transistors have any parasitic components that cause a significant delay when tied together?

Comment: @AmpliFire Yes, that's what I meant to say in the answer with "*there are parasitic capacitances that cause the signals to have delays*" -- it was used in the same sentence with the delays die to the semiconductor but, looking at it now, it's ambiguous. But, yes, the device, itself, has parasitic capacitances. They're one of the things that limit its high frequency usage.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest some sources where I can read more about transistors causing time delays?

Comment: @AmpliFire For example you could look at the description of the transistor as a small signal, and you'll see some amount of capacitance mentioned. They may not be mentioned as causing specific delays, but that's usually inferred (among other things).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd be looking that up.